# css background repeating when div height reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I have the following html/javascript implemented.  My goal is to have an image resize, while maintaining its aspect ratio, to take the height/width of the browser window.  However, when implementing this code, each resize event grows the div height by (old height + new height, instead of just setting it to new height.  How do I stop the div from growing in this way?

```
<div class="header-pc" style="background-image: url('assets/sunset-flipped1.png');background-size: 100% auto;height:1000px"></div>

function resizeHeaderPic(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.header-pc').height(height);f
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    //resizeHeaderPic();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resizeHeaderPic();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use Javascript for trivial CSS tasks.

```
body {
    background-image: url('assets/sunset-flipped1.png');
    background-size: cover;         /* Fit to cover entire element */
    background-position: center;    /* Where to scale from in the image */
}
```

And you're done without any HTML or Javascript.

Comment: This would work assuming you are using percentages, otherwise you still need some JavaScript.

Comment: This seems to work as long as the browser dimensions are larger than the original image; scaling it down by a lot causes empty space to appear off-screen.  To prevent this, I applied "overflow-x:hidden" to body and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Niels approach is good. You are setting the height of the div to window.height. But window height=window.Innerheight+scrollbar/toolbar. So every time it was being increased by the size of scrollbar.

```
function resizeHeaderPic(){
    var height = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.header-pc').height(height);
}
```